# Does the quality of white items give different craft results?

Tags: diablo-iii

Some of the new crafting recipes for legendary or set items require regular white items in order to craft them.

I've been saving superior or masterwork white items for eventual use in these crafts.  But it occurs to me that I have no idea if these are even worth keeping for this use.  On one hand, they're pretty rare to find, and that limits how many I can craft.  On the other, if they actually *do* provide better quality crafts, there's an advantage in using them.  But if they don't, I've been passing by lots of white items for no reason at all.

Does this level of quality for white items play any part at all in these crafts?

Comment: It never did in Diablo 2, and, AFAIK, it should not in Diablo 3. The white item is simply consumed, and new one is rolled. It makes no sense to complicate item-rolling functions in such a way, while not giving players clear understanding of what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

As of [patch 2.0.5](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/14138344/patch-205-now-live-5-13-2014#blacksmith).

> Legendary crafted recipes no longer require specific Common armors or
>   weapons and instead now require Common crafting materials

They also did NOT previously affect the quality of the items.

Comment: I know they don't *now*, but you have zero proof they didn't *before*.

Comment: Yes he does. Common freaking sense. The item is just consumed. The new item is created like any other item, the stats are rolled right when it is created.

Answer (score 0):

I can only say using my experience, but it makes no different. While crafting, reward is random for each type of item.